# How to validate an asp page with Validators to validate textbox to allow 2 different lengths of input?

Tags: regex, validation

I currently have a validation that allows only 6 digits input for a text box:

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator3" CssClass="footerAddValidator" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Invalid Number Entered" ControlToValidate="txtAddBin" ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="vgBinAdd" ValidationExpression="^[0-9]{6}$">*</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Is there any way to validate for 8 digits as well in the same validator, so if the user enters less then 6 or 7, it will fail

Answer (score 0):

I didnt understand if you want continue with 6 digits validation and add 8 digits validation or just have validation for 8 digits now.

So I did the two modes:

Regex for validate for 6 and 8 digits: `^([0-9]{8}|[0-9]{6})$`

Regex for only 8 digits validation: `^([0-9]{8})$`

I hope this help you!

Comment: Thank's, that works. But is that possible for this regular expression to allow only one word to be entered?

Comment: Could you give me some samples with valid words and invalid words to your case?

Comment: Thank you for your help. But, at the end, I do not need to check for that. I posted another related to that issue question here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55732080/right-after-asp-validation-fails-i-cannot-invoke-the-service-method-only-first